# python how to index a list and then select randomly from it

Tags: python, list, random, iteration

I have an "initial_list" that contains 100 strings. I'd like initial_list to index using "member". And from "member" I need to select 100 random members of the initial_list then I need to transfer them to a "second_list". My strategy is as follows:

```
      initial_list=[content]
      second_list=[]
      for member in range(0,len(initial_list)):
         randommember=random.randint(0,99)
         second_list.append(pop_array[randommember])
```

However the command keeps returning "'module' object has no attribute 'int'", because I can't seem to utilise member such that the random.int function can iterate through it. 
I am aware that I could do this using strings and random.choice() but I have ulterior reasons for using lists and random.int().
Any tips?

Comment: You're thinking of `random.randint()`.

Answer (score 2):

First, it's `random.randint`, not `random.int`. Second, you can't index an integer with another integer like you're doing with `[member]`. Third, you can simply use `second_list.append(random.choice(pop_array))`.

Comment: ok thanks a lot how do i get it to select 100 random members though as that command only appends one of the members?

Comment: Thumb up for `random.choice`.  This code is too long because not Pythonic.

Comment: Select 100 unique random members with `random.sample()`, or select 100 random members with replacement with `random.choice()` in a loop.

Comment: So something like this perhaps: for i in range(0,len(initial_list)):
    randommember=random.choice(0,99)#but where do I specify 'i'
    generations.append(initial_list[randommember])

Comment: or:  for i in range(0,len(initial_list)): randommember=random.sample(i,100)#but where do I specify 'i' generations.append(initial_list[randommember])

Comment: `random.choice(0,99)` is not valid. Please see the documentation for the `random` module.